# print_r() and mail() in PHP outputs something different, why?

Tags: php, magic-quotes

I have a html form where visitors can fill and send me some information, as an e-mail. It sends like this:

```
$body = print_r($_POST, true);

mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

When they write **abc'def** I get **abc\'def**

What is this additional `\`? How I can prevent it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because of magic quotes. See [here](http://pt.php.net/magic_quotes).

They don't output something different – the `$_POST` superglobal already has the backslash.

Answer (score 2):

That's most possible because you have **[magic quotes](http://pt.php.net/magic_quotes)** turned on, you can however, go about like this:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
   $new_text = stripslashes($text);
}
```

Now `$new_text` should output normally.

Comment: IMO, he should just disable the magic quotes. Those checks pollute the code and there's really no reason to have a server with magic quotes turned on.

Comment: @Artefacto: That's true, he should simply disable them. A good decision taken to strip them away from future versions as well :)

Comment: @Artefacto if the OP wants to build portable code for environments he has no control over, there is no way but to use these kinds of checks until PHP 6 is there.

Answer (score 2):

The backslash is an escape character - it lets the parser know that you don't want to use the single-quote in the normal way that PHP understands them. If you want to remove them in your output, use the [stripslashes](http://uk.php.net/stripslashes) method.

`string stripslashes ( string $str )`